# Adding the perovious field amount

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please note that I am having 2 tables:

I want the trnamt from table salary to get updated into tbl_emi in the rec record, but the amount should not exceed the emi amount for each record,for example in this case the amount 1000 which is in the salary table should be added 500 to the first record and another 500 to the second record to the tbl_emi table

```
               tbl_emi
EMI      DUEDT      REC     Acno
500    4/30/2014   500       123
500    5/30/2014   0         123 
500    6/30/2014   0         123 

              slary
         Acno      Trnamt
         123         1000
```

I used the below query but it is still adding on the rec field in tbl_emi tbale + the trnamt in salary table while it should not exceed the emi amount.

select query1: To create a temporary table for the accumlated emi

```
select a.emi, a.duedt, a.rec, a.acno, coalesce(sum(b.emi),0) as emi_accumulated
into #accumulated_amount5
from tbl_emi a
left join tbl_emi b on a.acno = b.acno and b.duedt < a.duedt
group by a.emi, a.duedt, a.rec, a.acno;
```

Query2: To create a temporary table for the salary amount

```
select a.*, s.RECAMT as salary_amt
into #accumulated_amount_with_salary5
from #accumulated_amount5 a
inner join Tbl_Fin s on a.acno = s.CARDNO;
```

Update Query1: To update the rec amount

```
update #accumulated_amount_with_salary5
set rec = rec + case
    when salary_amt < emi_accumulated then 0
    when (salary_amt - emi_accumulated) < emi then salary_amt - emi_accumulated
    else emi
end
```

Update Query2

```
update t
set lastrecdate=(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)), rec = a.rec
from tbl_emi t
    inner join #accumulated_amount_with_salary5 a on t.acno = a.acno and t.duedt = a.duedt
    --Finance
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the cumulative sum function, this is relatively easy by calculating the cumulative `emi` value and comparing to the `trnamt`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select e.*, sum(emi) over (partition by acno order by duedt) as cumemi
      from tbl_emi e
     )
update toupdate
    set rec = (case when trnamt > cumemi then emi
                    else trnamt - cumemi + emi
               end)
    from toupdate join
         slary
         on toupdate.acno = slary.acno and
            toupdate.cumemi - emi < trnamt;
```

Even without cumulative sum, you can still do the same thing using correlated subqueries.

EDIT:

In SQL Server 2008, you can express the cumulative sum as:

```
with toupdate as (
      select e.*,
             (select sum(e2.emi)
              from tbl_emi e2
              where e2.acno = e.acno and
                    e2.duedt <= e.duedt
             )  as cumemi
      from tbl_emi e
     )
update toupdate
    set rec = (case when trnamt > cumemi then emi
                    else trnamt - cumemi + emi
               end)
    from toupdate join
         slary
         on toupdate.acno = slary.acno and
            toupdate.cumemi - emi < trnamt;
```

Comment: Will this work on sql-server 2008, because it is showing me the error: Incorrect syntax near 'order'.

Comment: How did you create the topdate object?

Comment: @user2786306 . . . That was a typo.  It should be `toupdate`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use after insert trigger on salary table which will update the tbl_emi table after each insert in the salary table,
for reference how to create triggers in sql-server, refer to http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25600/Triggers-SQL-Server